# Powershell - Output formatting of Enums for ConvertTo-Json

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-remoting

For "*Get-Msoldomain*" powershell command-let I get the below output (*lets call it Output#1*) where Name, Status and Authentication are the property names and below are their respective values.

```
Name                    Status   Authentication

myemail.onmicrosoft.com Verified Managed
```

When I use the command with "ConvertTo-Json" like below

```
GetMsolDomain |ConvertTo-Json
```

I get the below output (*lets call it Output#2*) in Json Format.

```
{
    "ExtensionData":  {

                      },
    "Authentication":  0,
    "Capabilities":  5,
    "IsDefault":  true,
    "IsInitial":  true,
    "Name":  "myemail.onmicrosoft.com",
    "RootDomain":  null,
    "Status":  1,
    "VerificationMethod":  1
}
```

However, the problem is, that if you notice the **Status** property in both the outputs, it's different. Without using the ConvertTo-JSon Powershell gives the Text, and with using ConvertTo-Json it gives the integer.

Question -  How do I change my powershell script (i.e. `"Get-MsolDomain|ConvertTo-JSON"`) to make sure that the output contains the Status and Text and not Integer, because I am not querying specifically for Status property here. The output should convert all such properties to their Text values (from Int values)

Comment: I think this question is a better written alternative to the duplicate and should remain.

Comment: Thanks, I shall write it again